# libswt-gtk-3349.so missing on Debian 3.16

Tags: java, linux, gtk, debian

I am trying to execute a java project on debian 3.16 and I keep getting this message:

> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /tmp/libswt-gtk-3349.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
>   It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c ', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-gtk-3349 or swt-gtk in swt.library.path, java.library.path or the jar file
>       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.(Unknown Source)
>       at gui.MainWin.main(MainWin.java:912)

I look on Google for the problem and I installed all the recommended packages but still none of them had libswt-gtk-3349.so. I also installed all the gtk packages together with Eclipse, and still I am getting the same error.
Any suggestion on how could I solve this problem?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to unzip swt.jar and execute `file libswt-gtk-3349.so`. If the command indicate the .so is 32bit. It means your swt.jar is for 32bit Linux... Replace it with x86_64 version could fix the problem.

When 64bit Linux try to load a 32bit .so, but one of required .so is missing.
The error message will tell you the library not found. And most 64bit Linux does not install 32bit lib and caused the problem.

Comment: Hi beckyang, the problem, as you correctly said, it is that the swt was 32 bits. I downloaded the 64 bits version from the Internet and I replace it in the directory, but still I am getting the same error. Here is how I execute the aplication: java -D-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/opt/DUE-3.0/xulrunner -cp ./:./swt.jar:./sqlitejdbc-v037-nested.jar:./conjugador.jar:./com.johnspurlock.util.jar:./itext-2.0.4.jar:./jh.jar:./jhall.jar::./jhbasic.jar:./jsearch.jar:./hsviewer.jar:./due.jar:./commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:./lucene-core-2.2.0.jar:./lucene-queries-2.2.0.jar gui.MainWin Any idea?

Comment: Please execute `ldd libswt-gtk-3349.so` to check whether all required library exists. If **not found** displayed in the output, you can try to search the package include that .so file and install it. (Search keyword may be: `debain deb xxx.so`)

Comment: Beckyang I get this response: ldd libswt-gtk-3349.so
 linux-gate.so.1 (0xf776b000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xf7595000)
 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf776e000)

Comment: The output looks ok. What's your XULRunner version? (execute `/opt/DUE-3.0/xulrunner/xulrunner --version`)
Look like your program use SWT browser, please check [SWT FAQ](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserlinux) for more info.
"libswt-gtk-3349.so" is shiped with v3.3.x. Base on the version info, you may need to replace swt.jar with newer version or upgrade the XULRunner runtime.